# Resize circular progress in angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progress-bar, material-design

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) to build a directive for a login form:
[image]

When ever the user clicks login, a [circular progress](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.progressCircular) appears to indicate, that he is now being logged in. The progress does show and hide correctly, my problem is its size. I want it to be next to the login text at a similar size. I have tried to add `style="transform: scale(0.5)"` or `style="width: 20px"`, but neither affected its size.

How can I resize the progress, so it fits the text?

#### Template

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginCtrl.login()">
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label for="usr">Username</label>
        <input type="text" ng-disabled="login.loading" name="usr" id="usr" maxlength="50" ng-model="login.user" required />
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" ng-disabled="login.loading" name="pwd" id="pwd" ng-model="login.password" required />
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid || login.loading" type="submit">
        Login
        <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="login.loading" class="md-accent">
    </md-progress-circular></md-button>
</form>
```

#### Directive

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'AuthService', '$log', function ($scope, AuthService, $log) {
        $scope.login = {
            loading: false,
            password: '',
            user: ''
        };

        this.login = function () {
            $scope.login.loading = true;

            // Do the login, this might take longer
            AuthService.login($scope.login.user, $scope.login.password, function (data) {
                $scope.login.loading = false;

                if(data.success) {                  
                    $log.debug('login successful');
                }
                else {
                    $log.debug('login failed');
                }
            });
        };
    }])
    .directive('loginForm', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/templates/directives/loginForm.html'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the smaller value for `md-diameter` is not enough. The button changes its width and height. So here is my example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/1kohei1/pen/XbwMLQ) to show nice spinner in the button.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Your example on Codepen is not showing the progress circle. You have to remove the CSS "margin-top: -32px;" and it will be shown at the center of the button.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is searching for this:

You can add `md-diameter` to the progress directive. The documentation can be found [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.progressCircular/directive/mdProgressCircular).